# Linkage Problems

Tags: c++, linker

I have a file Images.h

```
    #ifndef IMAGES
#define IMAGES

#include<string>
#include<iostream>

#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

const std::string ImagePath = "C:/Users/Ivo/source/repos/ConsoleApplication163/ConsoleApplication163/Content/";
const std::string AudioPath = "C:/Users/Ivo/source/repos/ConsoleApplication163/ConsoleApplication163/Sound/";

class Image
{
public:

    Image()
    {

    }
    void play()
    {
        this->player.play();
    }

    void setTexture(const std::string& texture)
    {
        if (!this->texture.loadFromFile(ImagePath + texture))
            std::cout << "problem \n";
        shape.setTexture(&this->texture);
    }

    void setSound(const std::string& sound)
    {
        this->sound.loadFromFile(AudioPath + sound);
        player.setBuffer(this->sound);
    }

    sf::RectangleShape& getShape()
    {
        return this->shape;
    }

private:
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::RectangleShape shape;

    sf::SoundBuffer sound;
    sf::Sound player;
};

sf::SoundBuffer correctSound, incorrectSound;
sf::Sound correct, incorrect;

Image zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine;
Image zeroPlace, onePlace, twoPlace, threePlace;

void initializeImages()
{
    // IMAGES

    zero.setTexture("zero.png");

    zero.getShape().getTexture()->getSize();

    zeroPlace.setTexture("zeroPlace.png");

    zero.setSound("zero.wav");

    one.setTexture("one.png");
    onePlace.setTexture("onePlace.png");

    one.setSound("one.wav");

    two.setTexture("two.png");
    twoPlace.setTexture("twoPlace.png");

    two.setSound("two.wav");

    three.setTexture("three.png");
    threePlace.setTexture("threePlace.png");

    three.setSound("three.wav");

    // Audio
    correctSound.loadFromFile(AudioPath + "correct.wav");
    correct.setBuffer(correctSound);

    incorrectSound.loadFromFile(AudioPath + "incorrect.wav");
    incorrect.setBuffer(incorrectSound);

}
#endif
```

and I'm including this file in 2 other files getting those errors:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai9RP.png)

The problem is because of the global variables, when I remove them it is working fine, but could someone please tell me what's the reason ? After all I have those header guards, so they should be defined once ?
I heard something about Transition Unit, but I couldn't associate it.

Comment: Header guards prevent the same header body from being included twice in the *same* source file; not different source files. Thus each source gets its own global and you link to duplicate symbols. And fyi, the same problem would happen with `initializeImages`. I.e. that problem isn't just restricted to vars.

Comment: But for example if we had foo.h with header guards having a global variable and foo1.h with header guard including foo.h, also main.cpp including them both. It'll be fine because of the hearder guards, right ? isn't it the same situation ?

Comment: Defining global variables in header files is a **terrible** idea. You can extern *declare* them in the header, and put their formal definition in **one** source file. I.e. header has `extern Type somvar;` and **one** source file has `Type somevar;` Ideally you don't use globals *at all*, but if they must be shared across translation units (source files), do it like I just showed.